# why is my file system suddenly read only?

Tags: adb, htc-desire-hd, file-system, mount

Some background:

My HTC Desire HD has several issues.
**The first issue** being that I can not connect to it using a USB cable.

So I found that I can tell ADB to work over wifi and I was using this method for some time.
I am using VISIONary to temproot the device, then I run a terminal on the device and execute:

```
$ su
#setprop service.adb.tcp.port 5555
#stop adbd
#start adbd
```

I then use netcfg to find my device's IP and finally on my pc I use

```
adb connect {device IP}:5555
```

I am then able to run on my pc

```
adb shell
```

and use this shell to do the following:

```
cd /etc
echo 127.0.0.1 localhost >hosts
echo {my pc's IP} some.dnsname.com >>hosts
```

This is when **the second issue** comes into play: 
once in a while (seems related to killing and clearing cache of an app that uses some.dnsname.com - but not always) the hosts file just reverts to an empty file :(

Not having the deep knowledge to handle those problems (yet) I just "learned to live with them"...

A few moments ago, when I went through this process for for maybe the 30th time or so, A **new issue** decided to make my day more interesting.
I tried to modify (overwrite) the hosts file and I get the following  message:

```
cannot create hosts: read-only file system
```

I tried to read some about it and it seems I need to remount the system in read/write mode.

running

```
mount | grep system
```

returns

```
/dev/block/mmcblk0p25 /system ext3 ro,relatime,errors=continue,data=ordered 0 0
none /system/xbin tmpfs rw,relatime,gid=10132 0 0
```

**I need help with**:
1) Making my system read write again (what mount/remount command do I need to run?)
2) Understanding what could have caused this new issue.
3) Any ideas on how I can handle the two background issues is also most welcome.

thank you for reading...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`/system` is almost always read-only by default. Just remount it as R/W:

```
# mount -t ext3 -o rw,remount /dev/block/mmcblk0p25 /system
```

There's also [at least one app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.beansoft.mount_system&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5iZWFuc29mdC5tb3VudF9zeXN0ZW0iXQ..) that will attempt to do this for you, but it may not work on all devices.

Another option is to use `adb root` (if your ROM will allow it) to restart adbd as root, then simply issue `adb remount`. On ROMs where adbd is already running as root, the first command is unnecessary and `adb remount` will work right off the bat. From a PC:

```
C:> adb root
* Some response about success *
C:> adb remount
Remount succeeded
```

As to why it's getting blown away, is your device NAND unlocked? Many HTC devices will attempt to restore their `/system` partition to a stock state if they are NAND locked, making changes to `/system` fleeting at best. That's something of an educated guess, but the fact that you noted that you are using VISIONary to temproot seems to support that hypothesis.

Comment: adb root says:

adbd cannot run as root in production builds

Comment: @epeleg: You'll have to do it with `mount` then.

Comment: could you guess what has changed suddenly? I did this many many times and the system was never read-only.

Comment: @epeleg: I'm not entirely sure why it *wasn't* read-only to begin with, unless you're using a ROM that was modified to mount it as r/w on boot.

Comment: @epeleg: Actually, I thought of one possibility: VISIONary may have been mounting your system partition as r/w for you during the temproot process. If some system process then came along later and saw that the permissions were wrong, it could feasibly remount it read-only (which could be related to the NAND lock).

Comment: This is very likely. I later found out that something went wrong with VISIONary this time. It had hundreds of processes running on my phone. after a restart things now work as before. What does NAND locked mean? and how can I tell if this is the case with my phone ?

Comment: @epeleg: As far as I know it's basically synonymous with a locked bootloader. If you reboot to your bootloader and it doesn't say "Unlocked" anywhere then it's locked (`adb reboot bootloader` works for this, or `reboot bootloader` from an adb shell). The "Unlocked" text is usually pretty prominent on HTC devices near the top of the bootloader screen somewhere.

Comment: thanks for the additional info, I obviously have a lot more to learn about this OS. I could go on and as what is a locked bootloader and what does `adb reboot bootloader` do but maybe a more appropriate Q would be where can I read about all of this ?

Comment: @epeleg: The [CyanogenMod Wiki](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.com/index.php?title=Main_Page) and [XDA Wiki](http://forum.xda-developers.com/wiki/) are both pretty good resources. They both have glossary pages of common terms related to Android devices and rooting and such, though not a great deal of depth. Honestly, Google might be your best bet for really detailed reading. I don't think I have any links offhand because I've simply come across most of them on Google at some point in the past...

Comment: adb remount gives me 
`dm_verity is enabled on the system partition.
Use "adb disable-verity" to disable verity.
If you do not, remount may succeed, however, you will still not be able to write to these volumes.
remount of /system failed: Read-only file system
remount failed`

Answer (score 1):

This fixed it for me using android 11
Run android emulator with

```
Android/Sdk/emulator/emulator -avd Pixel_5_API_30 -writable-system --writable-system
adb shell
avbctl disable-verification
adb reboot
adb remount
adb shell
su
mount -o rw,remount -t ext4 /system
```

Make needed changes and change system back to read only with this

```
mount -o ro,remount -t ext4 /system
```